# como puedo guardar mis coordenadas en mysql usando "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, geolocalización

hola que tal amigo resulta que estoy muy atorada con este problema que me paso en el trabajo resulta que deseo guardar las coordenadas latitud y longitud en variable php para despues proceder a insertarlas en mysql pero no puedo hacer que las variable de javascript se pasen tal cual a las de php aca les dejo mi codigo para que lo analizan si me pudieran ayudar seria grandioso SALUDOS DESDE MEXICO

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn_ok, fn_error);

function fn_error(){

alert('Error');
}

function fn_ok(respuesta){

var lat = respuesta.coords.latitude;
var lon = respuesta.coords.longitude;


global=lat+' '+lon;
alert(global);
}

var global='hol';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$variablePHP = 
"<script type='text/javascript'>; 
var id=global;
  document.writeln(id) 
  alert(id);
  </script>";
echo $variablePHP;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui esta el codigo pero no logro hacer que la latitud y la longitus se guarden en las variables php si alguien sabe y me pudiera decir como resolver el problema me ayudaria bastante gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las opciones que puedes hacer es enviar las coordenadas por la URL y que se procesen en otro archivo:

```
//En Javascript:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn_ok, fn_error);

function fn_error(){

alert('Error');
}

function fn_ok(respuesta){

var lat = respuesta.coords.latitude;
var lon = respuesta.coords.longitude;

global="lat="+lat+'&lon='+lon;
var urlDestino = "http://fredyfx.com/index.cshtml?"+global;
//Esto genera: http://fredyfx.com/index.cshtml?lat=-8.1167518&lon=-79.0371252
alert(global);
window.open(urlDestino, '_self');
}
```

**Obteniendo las variables en PHP**

```
<?php $miLatitud = $_GET["lat"]; ?>
<?php $miLongitud = $_GET["lon"]; ?>
```

Comment: hola amigo la verdad me sirvió bastante tu opinión te lo agradezco bastante ya con esto puedo encontrar la solucion ERES LO MAXIMO

Comment: de nada :D estamos para servir, bienvenida a la familia de SOes. Te invito a darte una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y si la respuesta es la que mejor se acomodó a lo que buscabas, dale un check, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio :D saludos